# Changing an iPhone app id?

Tags: iphone

I would like to change the app id of an iPhone app that I am selling.

Is it possible to do so, update it, maybe add in-app purchases and have no problems?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

I did **not** change the bundle identifier. What I did was to create a new App Id in the *iPhone Developer Program Portal*. I first used a wildcard one and then to add the in-app purchase I created a specific one just for this app. I used the same id as I used first time I posted to the AppStore.

So, I did not change the App Id of the app. But this was how I solved this problem.

--

I did just that with one of my apps, ["Nya Öl"](http://www.memention.com/beers/)

I added a in-app purchase for a *Favorites List* in version 1.1

Comment: thanks... luckily i will not need the stored data files since the app is almost starting over...